# Application at context path can't start Tomcat 7 Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat

I am trying to run a webapp called TestServer2 in the Tomcat 7 running Ubuntu 14.04 but it gave failed as FAIL - Application at context path /TestServer2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT could not be started. I followed an example online [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/) and I tested it on my local Tomcat server instance running with Eclipse and it works just fine but when I deployed it into the server Ubuntu 14.04 with Tomcat 7 it gave me that error. Below are the codes I used:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestServer2</display-name>


  <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.heyho.rest.JSONService</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestServer2</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestServer2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.0.GA</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JSONService.java

```
package com.heyho.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
public class JSONService {


    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createProductInJSON(UserInput input) {

        String result = "User input submitted : " + input;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }



}
```

UserInput.java

```
package com.heyho.rest;


public class UserInput {

    int counter;
    String attribute;
    String publicKey;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }
    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }
    public String getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }
    public void setPublicKey(String publicKey) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User Input = counter " + counter + " attribute = " + attribute + " public key = " + publicKey ;

    }
}
```

ClientPost.java

```
package com.heyho.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ClientPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

        try {


            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                      .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true).build();

                    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                      .setSslcontext(sslContext)
                      .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                      .build();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                "http://somewebsite.de:50064/TestServer2/service/post");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<String,Object> test = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            test.put("counter", 1000);
            test.put("attribute", "user attribute");
            test.put("publicKey", "user public key");
            String json = gson.toJson(test);
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json);
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }


          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }

        }

    }
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Also how do I debug the Tomcat 7 running on the server so that it could give me some logs or error?

UPDATE

I have found the error in log something like this:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/heyho/rest/JSONService : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.heyho.rest.JSONService)
```

I'm not sure what is the problem here. I have declared JSONService on my web.xml but it still gives me error

Comment: First check the server logs for more information. They should be in /var/log/tomcat7

Comment: @Henry not much information that I could find, the best one is only SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 05, 2017 4:32:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/TestServer2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: Well that's just a summary error. Interesting are the mentioned "previous errors".

Comment: @Henry see my updated post i just found the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" means that the class `com.heyho.rest.JSONService` has been compiled for a newer version of Java as you try to run it with. Upgrade the JVM to 1.8 and it should work. Alternatively, you can make sure to compile the class for the version of the JVM.